# Why Web app not working in Telegram Android

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am developing a web application in Telegram. I am writing the front part in react js. Already uploaded the project to https hosting. The application opens and works fine on the Telegram desktop version and on iOS, but on Android the application is always a blank screen (only the background color changes when switching themes).

I also tried to simply upload other projects to the hosting, but this problem is only on android devices. I tested this problem on three different android devices and different versions. But other sites open normally (google.com, youtube.com).

I switched to debug mode on Android via PC as written in the documentation [Web App Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#debug-mode-for-web-apps) and when I started the application in telegram I got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'WebView')
at :1:17"

Comment: Solved this problem by changing the host server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.